# Multibinding for tooltip and ContentTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip, multibinding, datatemplateselector

How can I multibind a tooltip and ContentTemplateSelector to two or more properties ?Here is the skeleton  code:

```
<Grid>
     <Grid Definitions>
      <Content Control
          **Line A** *ToolTip*//Want to bind to the same two properties as in the Text Box below and invoke the converter
          **Line B** *ContentTemplateSelector*  //Want to bind to the same two properties as in the Text Box below and invoke the converter
       />  
       **Line C** <TextBlock
          <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                            <Binding Path="Property2" />
                        </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
<Grid Ends>
```

Looks like I cant use the MultiBinding way I have used for the textblock. My converter for the ContentTemplateSelector inherits the DataTemplateSelector control .Any workarounds/inputs appreciated. Also, I am unable to use a similar multibinding declaration for the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your question, you can set the `ToolTip` of the `ContentControl` the same way you did with text block, If the `ContentControl` is empty the tooltip won't show up.

For the `TemplateSelector`, just define two templates that use the `Multibinding` and the converter (make sure to bind the properties using `ElementName` to avoid the `UnserValue` scenario), and bind the `ContentTemplateSelector` of the `ContentControl` to your `DataTemplateSelector` that is set with the two defined `DataTemplates`, here is a full sample of how to do that:

MainWindow xaml:

```
<Window ...
 x:Name="Main"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  >
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CountToStringConverter x:Key="CountToStringConverter"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Property1" ElementName="Main"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Property2" ElementName="Main"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Property2" ElementName="Main"/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.Property1" ElementName="Main"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" FirstDataTemplate="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" SecondDataTemplate="{StaticResource SecondTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
            <ContentControl.ToolTip>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                    <Binding Path="Property2" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ContentControl.ToolTip>
        </ContentControl>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">

            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                    <Binding Path="Property2" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

TemplateSelector, Converter and Codebehind:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FirstDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate SecondDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // select your template based on item
        return (new Random()).Next(2)==0?SecondDataTemplate:FirstDataTemplate;
    }
}
public class CountToStringConverter:IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;            
        return values[0]?.ToString() + values[1]?.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _property1;
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _property1) return;
            _property1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _property2;
    public string Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _property2) return;
            _property2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();
        Property1 = "Property 1";
        Property2 = "Property 2";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

**Update**

As i said it should be easier to do that using DataTriggers, so define a `DataTrigger` for each one of your icons, and set the `ContentTemplate` according to the values of `property1` and `property2` using the same multivalues converter:

let's say you have two DataTemplates defined as so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WarningIconImageTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text"></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="/Icons/warningIcon.png"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CautionIconImageTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Some Other Text"></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="/Icons/cautionIcon.png"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:CountToStringConverter x:Key="CountToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Your DataTriggers should look something like this:

```
<ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger >
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Property2" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <system:String>Property 1Property 2</system:String>
                                <!--update based on your need-->
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource WarningIconImageTemplate}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="First ToolTip"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger >
                            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Property1"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Property2" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </DataTrigger.Binding>
                            <DataTrigger.Value>
                                <system:String>Property 2Property 1</system:String>
                                <!--update based on your need-->
                            </DataTrigger.Value>
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CautionIconImageTemplate}"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Second ToolTip"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
```

Now, if you want to bind the Icons, you could always do that using `ElementName` binding:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WarningIconImageTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Some Text"></TextBlock>
            <Image Source="{Binding DataContext.WarningImageSource,ElementName=Main}" ></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Another option that you might also consider is to define the `DataTrigger` in the `IconImageTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was trying to go ahead with your implementation. Actually, the control that I want to change based on the two bindings is an **icon** (image representing Warning,error, success). My Tempate selector returns something like this : `return (DataTemplate)App.Current.TryFindResource("WarningIconImage")`. From my understanding, I need to bind the source of the image to the DataTemplate returned and I am unable to achieve this. Any leads ?

Comment: So basically, when these two properties are changed, there are changes in lines marked as  Line A,Line B and Line C in the original code block of this question. Line A represents an icon(image), Line B the tooltip for the icon and Line C is the text. Line B and C is taken care of now. Line A is where I am struggling.

Comment: That looks more like a DataTrigger to me, why would you use a TemplateSelector in the first place !?
Assuming the TemplateSelector is the right choice for your case, what exactly would change between the different Icons' DataTemplates, only the Image Source ?

Comment: Yes, and the tooltip associated with that . You can refer to the comment above yours as well . Those are the three things I am trying to achieve due to the changes in the two properties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But, I can't follow the part where you have defined `<DataTrigger.Value>`. My understanding is that I have to define the values for the two properties (that I am binding to)here and when those two properties matches these values, the data trigger is fired. However, these are not static values that I can check against. I will try to explain in a better way in the next comment.

Comment: I have a grid that has 2 columns.Column 1 is  `ContentControl`(that hosts a `ContentTemplateSelector`(which is an icon returned by a _template selector class_ that is derived from  `DataTemplateSelector`). And column 2 is a `textblock`.The column 2 is multibound to the 2 properties marked as `Property1` & `Property2`. As a result, the `Textblock` value changes if `property1`/ `property2` changes. (Property1 and Property2 are objects. So when I say the `property1` or ` 2` changes, I mean any of the properties inside `property1` or `property2` changes).The content template(icon) does not update.

Comment: In case the below helps : Just checked out few more examples on  DataTrigger and most of the examples have a single value (as boolean - which is a static value that can be checked against). But in my case, the converters returns 5 possible strings and there are 3 icons templates corresponding to these 5 strings, i.e two sets of two strings share a same icon.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I incorrectly agreed about the comment yesterday where you asked about the change being only the image source. The above description clears the actual ask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932582/determining-value-of-contenttempateselector-based-on-two-properties. I have included the code for template selector and converter in this question .In case that helps to better understand what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

you can write any Property in one of two ways:

either:

```
<ContentControl ToolTip="Some Tooltip" />
```

or

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ToolTip>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CountToStringConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Property1"/>
            <Binding Path="Property2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentControl.ToolTip>
</ContentControl>
```